# How can I give grading in PHP table?

Tags: php, html

In this scenario, I created a table of student marks calculate average marks, lowest or highest marks. It's all working fine but I need do one more thing, calculate the grade according to particular data like this:

```
if marks is 85% and above, give grade A
if marks is 60% and above, give grade B
if marks is 55% and above, give grade C
if marks is 54% and less, mark them as Fail,
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Assignment 1</title>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <table class="table table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Physics</th>
          <th>Maths</th>
          <th>Chemistry</th>
          <th>Lowest Marks</th>
          <th>Highest Marks</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
<?php 
$marks = array( 
            "mohammad" => array(
                                "physics" => 35,        
                                "maths" => 30,      
                                "chemistry" => 39       
                            ),
            "qadir" => array(
                                "physics" => 30,
                                "maths" => 32,
                                "chemistry" => 29
                            ),
            "zara" => array(
                                "physics" => 31,
                                "maths" => 22,
                                "chemistry" => 39
                            )
            );                   
$average=0;
$lowest=0;
$greatest=0;
$physics=0;
$chemistry=0;
$maths=0;
$arr=Array(0);
$count=0;
foreach($marks as $row => $innerArray){
    $average=0;
    $lowest=0;
    $greatest=0;
    $count=0;
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>$row</td>";
    foreach($innerArray as $innerRow => $value){                                
        if($value>$greatest){
            $greatest=$value;
        }else{
            $lowest=$value;
        }
        echo "<td>$value</td>"; 
        $arr[$count]+=$value;
        $count++;                               
    }   
    $average=round($average/3,2);                           
    echo "<td>$lowest</td>";
    echo "<td>$greatest</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "<tr><td>Average Marks</td><td>".round($arr[0]/3,2)."</td><td>".round($arr[1]/3,2)."</td><td>".round($arr[2]/3,2)."</td></tr>";
?>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What about a simple `if-else` statement? ô.o

Answer (score 2):

Please try below code,

```html
<?php
$marks = $average;

if ($marks > 85) {
    echo "Grade A";
} else if ($marks > 60) {
    echo "Grade B";
} else if ($marks > 55) {
    echo "Grade C";
}
else{
    echo "Fail";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `switch/case` where the expression is `TRUE`:

```
switch (TRUE) {

case ($marks > 84) : $grade = 'A'; break;
case ($marks > 59) : $grade = 'B'; break;
case ($marks > 54) : $grade = 'C'; break;
default : $grade = 'Fail';

}
```